# Access all properties inside an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If i have an array of objects, how can i iterate through it?

For example this array

```
[{ name: "objc1", size: "small" }, { first: "objc2", size: "medium" }, { first: "objc3", size: "Big" }]
```

I can access each object with this:

```
for (var key in collection){

  alert(collection[key])  

}
```

But how can i go inside the object, to each property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don' t use `for ... in` over arrays, this approach has [several issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea). The `for ... in` is actually made for iterating over properties. Therefore, use the following (ES6):

```
for (const item of collection) {
  for (const key in item) {
    alert(key+': '+item[key]);
  }
}
```

On ES5, you need a loop like this:

```
var item;
for (var i=0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  item = collection[i];
  for (var key in item) {
    alert(key+': '+item[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Im using chrome. :(

Comment: Chrome is fine... supports many ES6 features already.

Comment: It says : var for is available only in ES6. :(. Im using freecodecamp.

Comment: I posted both ES6 and ES5 variants, the ES5 one should work (I just fixed a type though).

Comment: It says item is not defined...:(

Answer (score 0):

```js
var collection = [{ name: "objc1", size: "small" }, { first: "objc2", size: "medium" }, { first: "objc3", size: "Big" }];
collection.forEach(item =>{
  for (property in item){
    console.log(item[property]);
  };
});
```